# How to use mouse click and keyboard keys in combination / together to perform or call any function in JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I have a function which is called on click of a button i.e:

```
function print(){
alert("PRINT")
}

btn.addEventListener("click", print);
```

This will print as soon as button is clicked . But I want to call this function on the combination of keyboard key + mouse click i.e something like (q+click) i.e user press q key of keyboard and by clicking the q along mouse click . For control key it can be done easily , but for other keys how it could be done ??

Thanks

Comment: Look at this it can help you [Desktop_with_mouse_and_keyboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/Control_mechanisms/Desktop_with_mouse_and_keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

If you using RxJS, then you can achieve you wanted task more easily.

This is code for your task.

```
import { of, fromEvent, merge } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


const halloBtn = document.getElementById('hallo_btn');

const halloBtnClick$ = fromEvent(halloBtn, 'click');

const pressKey$ = fromEvent(document, 'keydown');

const keyUp$ = fromEvent(document, 'keyup');

let keydownFlag = false;

merge(
  halloBtnClick$,
  pressKey$,
  keyUp$
).subscribe(event => {
  if (event.type === 'keydown') {
    keydownFlag = true;
  }

  if (event.type === 'keyup') {
    console.log('key up ... ');
    keydownFlag = false;
  }

  if (keydownFlag && event.type === 'click') {
    alert('wow..');
    keydownFlag = false;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of the keys pressed and released for yourself

```js
"use strict";
console.clear()
{
  let keysPressed = {}
  
  const onKeyDown = e => {
    if (!e.repeat) {
      keysPressed[e.key] = true
    }
  }
  
  const onKeyUp = e => {
      delete keysPressed[e.key]
  }
  
  const onClick = e => {
    if (e.target.id == 'click-btn') {
      console.log('Keys pressed:', Object.keys(keysPressed).join(', '))
    }
  }
  
  document.addEventListener('click', onClick)
  document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown)
  document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp)
}
```

```html
<button id="click-btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply , for this approach is not working.

Comment: @NeerajN Why not?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be:

```
function print(event){
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    alert("PRINT")
  }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", print);
```